# Iframe - access information workaround

Tags: node.js

I have site that is on another domain and iframe access will not work. The site on other domain is a questionnaire with series of questions. Once the questions are completed that site will give me a number.

My task is allow a user on my site to go over those questions and to be able to access that number.

How can I achieve that? I was thinking to spin up a node server and have it fetch the complete site and serve it to me, something like mediator. That way I will not have CORS issues.

Is it possible to stream the complete page along with css/js to my frontend (backbone app)? Run it in the window for the user. Upon completion it can send the answer back to node, so node can post it and return the number to me.

I am open to any suggestions :)

Comment: yes, that is certainly possible. though, it would likely be easier to just fix the CORS problem if it is indeed your site (meaning you have the power to  modify it slightly)

Comment: I can modify my site but I am not sure I can modify the other one. Assume I can modify the remote site, what needs to be done on their side so that I can access the iframe data?